# Close PrettyPhoto after a given delay

Tags: jquery

I am trying to close the prettyPhoto modal window after a given time. This time will vary so it needs to be attached to this line and not modified in the plugin.

I need to know the working version of this (as this one doesn't seem to behave):

`$.prettyPhoto.delay(500).close();`

The `$.prettyPhoto.close();` works as normal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try using a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.prettyPhoto.close();
}, 500);
```

Comment: thank you. the spec of the project changed a bit so now I am using ajax which will delay the closing based on the loading time therefore I don't need to use the setTimeout function.